# Determining Direct (Aerial) Distance between two Geo-Locations

Tags: here-api

I am using calculate route api to get distance between two geo locations. Calculate route returns "route not found" for the geo locations that are not connected by road. How can I get air distance between two geo locations like bangalore and chicago. Which are not connected by road. I am confused since I am not able to find a dedicated mode of transport for air distance.

Comment: you can do this quite simple on your side via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula

Answer (score 0):

Our APIs do not support aerial mode of transport. Supported modes of transport are: 
`car | pedestrian | carHOV | publicTransport | publicTransportTimeTable | truck | bicycle`. The API will not return any information including distance once a route could not be found.,